# Web3Js: TypeError: hexToBytes: expected string, got object

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx

I am trying to sign a transaction, but I'm receiving this error:

```
hexToBytes: expected string, got object
TypeError: hexToBytes: expected string, got object
    at hexToBytes (~\node_modules\@noble\secp256k1\lib\index.js:525:15)
    at ensureBytes (~\node_modules\@noble\secp256k1\lib\index.js:544:63)
    at initSigArgs (~\node_modules\@noble\secp256k1\lib\index.js:825:16)
    at signSync (~\node_modules\@noble\secp256k1\lib\index.js:861:28)
    at ecsign (~\node_modules\@ethereumjs\util\src\signature.ts:21:41)
    at Transaction.sign (~\node_modules\@ethereumjs\tx\src\baseTransaction.ts:332:31)
    at Object.sign (~\tests\web3.test.ts:128:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Here is the source code:

```
import {Transaction} from "@ethereumjs/tx";
// ...

const txData = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
    to: "0x0cacfcb46deeceaf221dbd853e42f41ff8cd0cbd",
    value: web3.utils.toHex("100000000000000"),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex("10000000000"),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex("21000")
};

console.log("Raw: ", txData);

const privateBuffer = Buffer.from(prviKey.substr(2), 'hex');

const tx = new Transaction(txData);
tx.sign(privateBuffer)

const serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString('hex')

console.log('tx :', tx)
console.log('serializedTx :', serializedTx)
```

Comment: What version of `@ethereumjs/tx` are you using? When v3 was released it had several changes needed by recents changes in Ethereum. Check their README for the new syntax. https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx#readme.

Comment: @Ismael I created an issue on the repo and so if you want to check it out here is the link: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/issues/2374